# Easy to remember fingerprints for data?

Tags: hash, visualization, fingerprint

I need to create fingerprints for RSA keys that users can memorize or at least easily recognize. The following ideas have come to mind:

- Break the SHA1 hash into portions of, say 4 bits and use them as coordinates for Bezier splines. Draw the splines and use that picture as a fingerprint.
- Use the SHA1 hash as input for some fractal algorithm. The result would need to be unique for a given input, i.e. the output can't be a solid square half the time.
- Map the SHA1 hash to entries in a word list (as used in spell checkers or password lists). This would create a passphrase consisting of real words.
- Instead of a word list, use some other large data set like Google maps (map the SHA1 hash to map coordinates and use the map region(s) as a fingerprint)

Any other ideas? I'm sure this has been implemented in one form or another.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/) contains something like that, under the name "visual host key". Try this:

```
ssh -o VisualHostKey=yes somesshhost
```

where `somesshhost` is some machine with a SSH server running. It will print out a "fingerprint" of the server key, both in hexadecimal, and as an ASCII-art image which may look like this:

```
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|   .+            |
|   + o           |
|  o o +          |
|   + o +         |
|  . o E S        |
|   + * .         |
|    X o .        |
|   . * o         |
|   .o .          |
+-----------------+
```

Or like this:

```
+--[ RSA 1024]----+
|        .*BB+    |
|       . .++o    |
|        = oo.    |
|       . =o+..   |
|        So+..    |
|        ..E.     |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

Apparently, this is inspired from techniques described in [this article](http://sparrow.ece.cmu.edu/~adrian/projects/validation/validation.pdf). OpenSSH is opensource, with a BSD-like license, so chances are that you could simply reuse their code (it seems to be in the [`key.c`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/key.c?rev=1.90&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) file, function `key_fingerprint_randomart()`).

Comment: This is worth looking into if you are confined to ASCII output.

Answer (score 2):

For item 3 (*entries in a word list*), see **RFC-1751** - **A Convention for Human-Readable *128-bit* Keys**, which notes that

> The authors of **S/Key** devised a system to make the 64-bit one-time
> password easy for people to enter.
>
> Their idea was to transform the password into a string of small
> English words.  English words are significantly easier for people to
> both remember and type.  The authors of S/Key started with a
> dictionary of 2048 English words, ranging in length from one to four
> characters.  The space covered by a 64-bit key (2^64) could be covered
> by six words from this dictionary (2^66) with room remaining for
> parity.  For example, an S/Key one-time password of hex value:
>
> ```
>     EB33 F77E E73D 4053
> ```
>
> would become the following six English words:
>
> ```
>     TIDE ITCH SLOW REIN RULE MOT
> ```

You could also use a compound fingerprint to improve memorability, like english words followed (or preceeded) by one or more key-dependent images.

For generating the image, you could use things like [Identicon](http://identicon.net/), [Wavatar](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=1462), [MonsterID](http://www.splitbrain.org/projects/monsterid), or [Robo](http://robohash.org/)[Hash](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2742367).

Example:

> [image]
> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]
>
> TIDE ITCH SLOW
>
> REIN RULE MOT

Answer (score 0):

I found something called random art which generates an image from a hash. There is a Python implementation available for download: http://www.random-art.org/about/

There is also a paper about using random art for authentication: http://sparrow.ece.cmu.edu/~adrian/projects/validation/validation.pdf

It's from 1999; I don't know if further research has been done on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion (draw the path of splines for every four bytes, then fill using the [nonzero fill rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties)) is exactly what I use for visualization in [hashblot](http://hashblot.com).